# IPagedList - 2 different sources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have to implement Paging for keyword search results. The search may return Home results and community results. (This is for a real estate site). So there are 2 types to display. I need to implement paging for the results shown using IPagedList. I see that IPagedList have only one source? 
is it possible to have 2 sources and implement paging?
Can some one give idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two types implement a common interface and use `IPagedList<ISharedInterface>` as view model. If you can share what info you want to display from both types it would be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of the PagedList library here.

You could always make it an IPagedList if you want to go with the nuclear option.